# split array and create dynamic series?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, plot

I have plotted with javafx a set of series. My problem is that I have to split an array of elements in X groups (eg 50) and for each of these groups should create the series to be plotted on one ScatterChart. How can I split the array into small series?
The array size is therefore variable should I create a serial number in a dynamic way, how to do? below place a portion of my code:

```
try {
      extractedData = SpectrumExtractor.extractionSpectrum(file);
      XYChart.Series<Number,Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number,Number>();
      List<ArrayList<Double>> extractedDataList = Arrays.asList(extractedData);
      List<List<Double>>partitions = ListUtils.partition(extractedData,512);
      for (List<Double> partition : partitions) {
        for(int i =0; i<partition.size(); i++){
         series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(i, partition.get(i)));
        }
    }   
     ChartSpectrum.getData().addAll(series);
```

...

I have split the array, now how do I dynamically create more series to print several lines of Linechart? I would like to obtain a graph similar to that in the image (
for now I can only get a single serie and therefore a single line) :

[image: LineChart]

Comment: Can you  add more details about the data contained in the array and what do you mean when you say, "How can I split the array into small series?" I am guessing you want to create multiple series from the same array?

Comment: yes, I want to do just that.

Comment: extractedData is an  ArrayList<Double>;

Comment: It depends on how many series you want. You can then apply an algorithm to split the parent Array into the decided number of child arrays.

Comment: I updated the code and the question

Comment: What is the size of your parent List and what is the size of each child list that you want to create?

Comment: Do you have a fixed amount of series that you want in your Graph. The image posted by you has 3 series. You need to have one constant to be able to write the splitting algorithm and then plot a graph using it.

Comment: exact thit is the problem I do not have a fixed size. the size of parent List is variable and depend on the file that I choose for analysis. And the size of child List is fixed to 512.

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of Series that you want to show in the graph. For example, if you were plotting a LineGraph, would you want to show 3 lines or 4 lines?

Comment: yes, I want show at least 10 lines, can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) which provides [ListUtils.partition(List< T >, int)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)) like so:

```
// assuming extractedData is of type Number[]:
List<Number> extractedDataList = Arrays.asList(extractedData);
// the last partition might have less than 50 elements
List<List<Number>> partitions = ListUtils.partition(extractedDataList, 50);

for (List<Number> partition : partitions) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Now I was able to divide the array into groups of 50, now how do I create as many as the group number? (I have 25 arrays of 50 points) how do I create 25 different series dynamically? (25 number may vary)